# How to locate an element in a table list row

Tags: python, selenium, html-table, webdriver, element

I am trying to automate salesforce, however i am having some trouble with the locators. I am using Python and selenium webdriver to do this.

I am trying to click on this element (snippet given):

```js
< th scope = "row"
class = " dataCell  cellCol1 " > < a href = "javascript:srcUp(%27%2F0019E00000SLiUQ%3FsrPos%3D0%26srKp%3D001%26isdtp%3Dvw%27);"
data - seclke = "Account"
data - seclkh = "73556054e04c9691f20b5b34809356fd"
data - seclki = "0019E00000SLiUQ"
data - seclkp = "/0019E00000SLiUQ"
data - seclkr = "1"
onmousedown = "searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" > Harris Kemp < /a></th >
```

however, for some reason it can't locate it.

I have tried different solutions that i found online and none of them seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
    # driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("history-iframe"))
    # mouseDown() // i entered the location of the element here
    # pyautogui.click() // i entered the location of the element here
```

Here is another way that I tried:

```
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-seclkr='1']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

I have used all different xpaths available and it still won't click on it.

It would be really grateful if someone could help out please.

[I have attached the full html body image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbMX9.jpg)

Comment: Please make sure that you give a brief explanation of what you are trying to do in the beginning. The snippet can be pasted afterwards. Somebody might downvote your question because of this. For your answer now, I am trying to find something similar and I will answer when I arrive home :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Apolo Radomer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To locate the "Edit" element, you could do:

```
elem1= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='actionColumn']")
elem1.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='actionLink']").click()
```

if you want to click "Harris Kemp", try:

```
elem1= driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//th[@scope='row']")
elem1.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@data-seclke='Account' and text()='Harris Kemp']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, that would click on the edit button if you look at the attached image i am trying to click on the name 'Harris Kemp' in the table.

I tried this:

`elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class=' dataCell  cellCol1 ']")
        elem1.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@data-seclkp='/0019E00000SLiUQ']").click()`

and it didnt work :(

Comment: @zplush Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @zplush from your question, seems that you want to click the "Edit" element

Comment: yes sorry thats my bad, i copied the wrong bit in ive corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

Can you pick a simple a tag from the site and try something like the below?

Let's say that this is the HTML script:

```
<div id='a'>
  <div>
    <a class='click'>abc</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

your python script should be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']//a[@class='click']")
```

The output should be:

```
<a class="click">abc</a>
```

and then try to put the `.click()` in the end of your python code

Comment: I think we pasted the answer with DurdenP simultaneously :D Try his script. It should work.